# Cron - How to run a job on the first weekday after a specific day of the month?

Tags: unix, cron

We want to schedule a job that runs on a weekday on the 12th or on the first weekday after the 12th. Can I specify that in cron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define such logic in `cron` and the usual way is to add it in to the script you want to run. So run the script every day like this:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

and add inside

```
if [ "$(date +%d%m)" == "0101" ]
then rm -f /var/run/flag
fi
if [ $(date +%d) -ge 12 ] && [ $(date +%w) -gt 0 ] &&  [ $(date +%w) -lt 6 ] && [ ! -f /var/run/flag ]
then <do the work>
touch /var/run/flag
fi
exit
```

Also you should take care to run only once (as far as I understand)

Comment: Won't this run too often?  For example, the conditional is true both yesterday (Wednesday, February 12th, _%d_ = 12 and _%w_ = 3) and today (Thursday, February 13th, _%d_ = 13 and _%w_ = 4).  Doesn't the OP want the cronjob to run once and only once monthly?  Also, isn't this question better suited for [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: @pilcrow, probably that is what OP want, and I mention it in my last sentence :) Not sure if its for serverfault, but tag shell, bash, will be appropriate IMHO

Comment: But you don't show the OP how to run it once! :)  You showed him how to run it every weekday in a month greater than or equal to the 12th day of the month.  He could do that himself with `0 0 12-31 * 1-5` and no change to his script.  I understand that he accepted your answer, but your answer doesn't answer his question.